# Sending form POST request to PHP

Tags: php, html, post

I want to send a couple of form fields as a POST request to my PHP page, but I can't get it to work.  Here is my code:

PHP `login.php`

```
<?php

if(!ISSET($_POST["username"]) && !ISSET($_POST["password"])) {
    include "login.html";
}
else {
    echo "hi";
}

?>
```

HTML `login.html`

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" id="username"/>
    <label for="password">Password</label>Password<input type="password" id="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: You should learn to love [the `label` element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/).

Answer (score 5):

Your inputs do not have `name`s. The `id` is used for client-side referencing, but it is the (non-unique) `name` attribute that is used to determine the key for a value when the data is submitted. A form control cannot be *successful* (i.e. in the form data) without a `name`.

Comment: Ohh ok thanks! I saw this page http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp and thought that name was depracated

Comment: That says: *In XHTML, the name attribute **of the `<a>` tag is deprecated**, and will be removed.* `<input>` is not `<a>`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included the `name` attribute in your html input elements. name attribute is used when passing form information to the webserver. `id` is primarily used for javascript based manipulation.

```
Username<input type="text" name="username"/>
Password<input type="password" name="password"/>
```